# Puppet Dashboard with Resource Definitions

Tags: dashboard, puppet, configuration-management

I have a puppet environment where I need to add a variable number of very similar objects to a single server. The objects vary only by attributes such as name and path, all of which can be extrapolated from a single name parameter.

This seems like the perfect use for puppet resource definitions since multiple definitions can be added to a single server and their specific attributes can be taken from the definition name declaration.

This setup works well for me and I have had no issues getting it up and running on several servers. I have a requirement now however to hand this over to an ops department with almost no scripting experience, so they aren't really comfortable managing from the file system.

They requested a dashboard, so I setup puppet dashboard for them. After I set the dashboard up however, I found out that it only supports adding classes to servers, not definitions. This seems pretty shortsighted on the part of the folks at PuppetLabs, so I can only think that I am approaching this problem the wrong way and that there must be a solution using classes whereby multiple almost identical entities can be added to a single node.

I realize I could create a class for each entity, but there are hundreds, even thousands of potential variations so that's not really practical.

I have also considered a wrapper class that declares each definition on a per node basis, but this seems like more work to manage than it's worth.

Any thoughts on alternate approaches that would be compatible with the dashboard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make ENCs such as dashboard work this way, you have to pass in node data in the form of node variables. Note that [Hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/) is often preferable to plain node variables.

Generally, the value you want to hand in is an array of your resource titles

```
$resources = [ "name1", "name2", ... ]
```

Then classify your node with (at least) one class that instanciates your defined type using this data, e.g.

```
class my_resources {
    my_defined_type { $resources: }
}
```